# Sklearn equivalent to statsmodel logit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have a dataframe `df` with

`df.head()`

[image]

(3, 3 and 6 levels for variables F1, F2, and F3), and run the code

```
from patsy.contrasts import Sum
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

model = 'SEL ~ C(F1, Sum) + C(F2, Sum) + C(F3, Sum)'
model = smf.logit(model, data=df)
model_fit = model.fit()
```

1) What would be the equivalent of the above using sklearn?

2) What would be the equivalent of the above using sklearn but dropping "Sum" on the first assignment to the model variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something that gives you a onehot encoding, and basically removing the last level, and insert -1 in those rows which correspond to the last level:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing

def contrSum(DF,column):
    DF[column] = DF[column].astype('category')
    nlevels = len(DF[column].unique())
    dm = pd.get_dummies(DF[column],prefix=column,dtype=np.int64)
    dm.loc[dm[dm.columns[nlevels-1]]==1,dm.columns[:(nlevels-1)]] = -1
    return dm.iloc[:,:(nlevels-1)]

contrSum(df,'F1')

    F1_1    F1_2
0   1   0
1   0   1
2   1   0
3   0   1
4   0   1
... ... ...
95  1   0
96  -1  -1
97  1   0
98  0   1
99  -1  -1
```

Now we apply this function to all the columns, concatenate and fit:

```
dmat = pd.concat([contrSum(df,'F1'),contrSum(df,'F2'),contrSum(df,'F3')],axis=1)
clf = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(dmat,df['SEL'])
```

Let's plot:

```
prob = clf.predict_proba(dmat)[:,1]
plt.scatter(x=model_fit.fittedvalues,y=np.log(prob/(1-prob)))
```

[image]

Look at coefficients:

```
pd.DataFrame({'sk_coef':clf.coef_[0],'smf_coef':model_fit.params[1:]})

    sk_coef smf_coef
C(F1, Sum)[S.1] 0.007327    0.023707
C(F1, Sum)[S.2] -0.337868   -0.375865
C(F2, Sum)[S.1] -0.174720   -0.192799
C(F2, Sum)[S.2] 0.018365    0.031589
C(F3, Sum)[S.1] 0.197189    0.251827
C(F3, Sum)[S.2] 0.058658    0.045554
C(F3, Sum)[S.3] -0.103133   -0.148508
C(F3, Sum)[S.4] -0.209002   -0.265786
C(F3, Sum)[S.5] 0.238623    0.303353
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to avoid running the statsmodel first as I cannot run statsmodel for some reason on a specific machine. However I can run sklearn, so I wonder if I can run equivalent code in sklearn independently. Maybe I should have mentioned that.

Comment: hmmm can you run patsy then? the contrast part will take a bit of coding

Comment: unfortunately no... Statsmodel and patsy have a dependency conflict issue on my machine which I haven't been able to solve up to now..